# While doing git checkout in Jenkins, The error around SSL certificates "PKIX path building failed" keeps coming back every day even after being fixed

Tags: java, git, jenkins, ssl-certificate

I have a jenkins installation running currently with version 2.332.2 using java 11.0.14.1 . While attempting connections to git repositories(via github branch source plugin) it showed an error for PKIX path building failed, which I figured out with the help of stackoverflow that it was about jre not recognizing the ssl certificates for github. This is already solved on various posts and i was able to download the cer file from my browser and import it into the cacerts file. It started working on day 1.
Day 2 , it agains starts showing the same error and even after attempting import of certificate again, it did not work. I tried importing with the same alias and it showed that it already exists. I tried with using a different alias as well and it got imported successfully but to no avail.
One of the existing posts suggested a hack to install a plugin skip-certificates-check to disable this entirely and since our jenkins is operating in closed company network only, I installed it and it worked for me on day 2.
Day 3 , the error has popped up again, the certificates are still there , the plugin is still there but the ghost of pkix is back to haunt me.
I have run out of options other than using a complete new jenkins installation.

The error shown:

```
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434)
Caused: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:313)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:222)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:129)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1341)
Caused: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:352)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:295)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:290)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1357)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1232)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1175)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:443)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:421)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:182)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1501)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1411)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:451)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:422)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.kt:379)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.kt:337)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.kt:209)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:226)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:106)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.kt:74)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.initExchange$okhttp(RealCall.kt:255)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:32)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:95)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at org.kohsuke.github.extras.okhttp3.ObsoleteUrlFactory$UnexpectedException.lambda$static$0(ObsoleteUrlFactory.java:1365)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.execute(RealCall.kt:154)
    at org.kohsuke.github.extras.okhttp3.ObsoleteUrlFactory$OkHttpURLConnection.getResponse(ObsoleteUrlFactory.java:671)
    at org.kohsuke.github.extras.okhttp3.ObsoleteUrlFactory$OkHttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(ObsoleteUrlFactory.java:702)
    at org.kohsuke.github.extras.okhttp3.ObsoleteUrlFactory$DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(ObsoleteUrlFactory.java:1064)
    at org.kohsuke.github.internal.GitHubConnectorHttpConnectorAdapter.send(GitHubConnectorHttpConnectorAdapter.java:87)
    at org.kohsuke.github.GitHubClient.sendRequest(GitHubClient.java:384)
Caused: org.kohsuke.github.HttpException: Server returned HTTP response code: -1, message: 'null' for URL: https://api.github.com/rate_limit
    at org.kohsuke.github.GitHubClient.interpretApiError(GitHubClient.java:548)
    at org.kohsuke.github.GitHubClient.sendRequest(GitHubClient.java:399)
    at org.kohsuke.github.GitHubClient.getRateLimit(GitHubClient.java:230)
    at org.kohsuke.github.GitHubClient.rateLimit(GitHubClient.java:285)
    at org.kohsuke.github.GitHubRateLimitChecker.checkRateLimit(GitHubRateLimitChecker.java:124)
    at org.kohsuke.github.GitHubClient.sendRequest(GitHubClient.java:383)
    at org.kohsuke.github.GitHubClient.fetch(GitHubClient.java:121)
    at org.kohsuke.github.GitHubClient.checkApiUrlValidity(GitHubClient.java:323)
    at org.kohsuke.github.GitHub.checkApiUrlValidity(GitHub.java:1244)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.github_branch_source.ApiRateLimitChecker.verifyConnection(ApiRateLimitChecker.java:199)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.github_branch_source.Connector$GitHubConnection.verifyConnection(Connector.java:794)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.github_branch_source.Connector.connect(Connector.java:447)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.github_branch_source.GitHubSCMSource.retrieveActions(GitHubSCMSource.java:1999)
    at jenkins.scm.api.SCMSource.fetchActions(SCMSource.java:848)
    at jenkins.branch.MultiBranchProject.computeChildren(MultiBranchProject.java:597)
    at com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.ComputedFolder.updateChildren(ComputedFolder.java:278)
    at com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.FolderComputation.run(FolderComputation.java:166)
    at jenkins.branch.MultiBranchProject$BranchIndexing.run(MultiBranchProject.java:1031)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:101)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:442)
```

The cacerts file I update resides under the java.home path that is shown under System Information in Manage Jenkins , and it worked for me once, so I am quite positive the path is correct.
Installing the skip-certificate-check-plugin also worked for me for a day.
Also the machine/jenkins remained on the entire time and nothing was restarted across my day 1,2,3. So I am not sure at what point it really breaks.
Since I am using a multi branch pipeline Project, switching to cli version of git would require creating an entire unit in itself to scan for git changes via cli, trigger projects, and have no idea about how to create new projects for a new branch detected on git repo. That's why not inclined towards using git cli via execute shell.

Comment: I sort of fixed the issue by removing all Git related plugins and reinstalling them. Hope it does not come back again